# Perl reduce() fails with -d:Profile

Tags: perl, debugging, profiling

The function `reduce()` does not work properly under -d:Profile. Is it a known bug? If yes, how do I profile a program that contains this function? If not, where do I report the bug?

A working example: file `bad.pl` contains

```
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/reduce/;

print reduce { $a + $b } (1, 2);
```

Then running it, I get:

```
C:\Test>perl bad.pl
3
C:\Test>perl -d:Profile bad.pl
Use of uninitialized value $b in addition (+) at bad.pl line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $a in addition (+) at bad.pl line 5.
0
```

I got the same results in Windows under Strawberry Perl and in CentOS.

Comment: Devel::NYTProf has been recommended over Devel::Profile for as long as I can remember.

Comment: I also suggest switching to Devel::NYTProf, but a workaround might be to something like `use if $INC{'Devel/Profile.pm'}, 'List::Util' => qw(reduce); BEGIN { *reduce = sub (&@) {...} unless __PACKAGE__->can('reduce') };` to provide a pure Perl `reduce` implementation when running under Devel::Profile .